# See what in a service takes CPU Edit: (Many Threads...)

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, service, cpu

I have a C# Service, that is quite big, it works as a server application having communication with a few (about 5) clients at the same time. Each client is a Thread that mostly puts data in and takes data out of a Access database. The service works well when its started, but after a few days the CPU just goes wild (up on 99%) and the service starts to slow down alot. I dont know what is causing this... Is there anyway to see WHAT in a service that takes the CPU, what function och thread? Dont know how to describe it better, but just ask questions if you need more info to help! :)

/Nick

EDIT: Added code on how I create threads and what they do.... (After i used Process Expolorer i noticed I hade alot running)

```
private void ListenForClients()
{
            this.tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                Connection c = new Connection(this.parent);
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(c.HandleClientComm));

                threadCollection.Add(clientThread);
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
}

public void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        try
        {

            TcpClient server = (TcpClient)client;

            NetworkStream ns = server.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            string input, stringData;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    data = new byte[1024];
                    if (ns.DataAvailable && ns.CanRead)
                    {
                        int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        if (recv > 0)
                        {
                            if ((byte)data[recv - 1] == (byte)255)
                            {
                                int cnt = -1;
                                for (int i = 0; i < recv; i++)
                                {
                                    if (data[i] == (byte)254)
                                        cnt = i;
                                }

                                int nr = recv - cnt - 2;
                                byte[] tmp = new byte[nr];

                                for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
                                {
                                    tmp[i] = data[cnt + i + 1];
                                }
                                string crc = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmp);
                                stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, cnt);

                                MsgStruct msgs = new MsgStruct(stringData);
                                msgs.setCrc(crc);
                                Thread.Sleep(200);

                                addTodo(msgs);
                            }
                        }


                    }
                    if (parent.cStructHandler.gotMsg(this.ID))
                    {
                        MsgStruct tmpCs = parent.cStructHandler.getNextMsg(this.ID);

                        if (tmpCs.getMsg().Length != 0 && ns.CanWrite)
                        {
                            byte[] ba = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmpCs.getMsg());

                            if (tmpCs.getCrc() == "")
                            {
                                ulong tmp = CRC.calc_crc(ba, ba.Length);
                                tmpCs.setCrc(tmp.ToString("X"));
                            }

                            if (tmpCs.canSendByTimeout())
                            {
                                string crcStr = "?" + tmpCs.getCrc() + "?";
                                byte[] bb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(crcStr);
                                crcStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb);
                                byte[] fullMsg = new byte[ba.Length + bb.Length];
                                bb[0] = 254;
                                bb[bb.Length - 1] = 255;

                                ba.CopyTo(fullMsg, 0);
                                bb.CopyTo(fullMsg, ba.Length);
                                string s = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fullMsg);

                                ns.Write(fullMsg, 0, fullMsg.Length);
                                Thread.Sleep(200);
                                if (!tmpCs.isAckNeeded())
                                    parent.cStructHandler.removeNextMsg(this.ID);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            ns.Close();
            server.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Attach a debugger and have a look?

Comment: when do you leave the while(true) in case no exception occurs? see my updated answer please.

Comment: If an anwser solved the problem or shed some light on the solution, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use some kind of tracing, just to see what your appication is doing:

Here is a simple logging framework for dot net [log 4 net Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial)

And: As you stated it is a long running server process, I recommend using
rolling logs (i.e. if a logfile has a certain amount of lines, a new file 
is used). The log4net RollingFileAppender comes in handy.

You should use a high level of tracing for the standard case (i.e. while 
everything is working just fine) and be able to switch to lower levels
with more output when in need (i.e. when your serverprocess goes amok).

And, of course, you could have a look via the [jetbrains tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

Also highly recommend are those RedGate Tools: [ANTS performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/index-1?utm_expid=53846-2&utm_referrer=http://www.red-gate.com/) and the [Dot Net Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)

**EDIT**

Almost forgot to mention: One of my favorite tools of all times: [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

**EDIT2**

In case of work done, you will need a break to leave the while true, i think

Comment: I checked with Process Explorer and had ALOT of threads running, wouldnt they stop when the function is done running (clients disconnects)? I edited in some code in my first post for you to look at!

Comment: oh... i believe it never really leaves the while(true) part, thus never ending the thread, thus having more and more threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check opened handles (files).
I bet you forgot to free native resources (forgot about `using` construction)

Answer (score 0):

Main issue in your code is that you are generating threads indefinitely and probably not freeing them at all in threadCollection.

Maybe [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct) "fire & forget" is better in your case?